# nopcommerce 3.5 database connection string (settings.txt missing)

Tags: database-connection, nopcommerce

I have installed nopCommerce 3.5 on visual studio 2010 but after a successful configuration i could not find any database connection string file which should be under Nop.Web/App_Data/Settings.txt. so there is no Settings.txt file in my project at all and I am using MSSql 2012, Database has been created as expected including sample data. so where is my database connection string please?

Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 4):

Just create a file called "Settings.txt" in App_Data and copy the following 2 lines in it. You need to modify the connection string to suit your environment. I have replaced my details with capitals.

```
DataProvider: sqlserver
DataConnectionString: Data Source=SERVER_NAME\DB_INSTANCE;Initial Catalog=YOUR_DB_NAME;Integrated Security=True;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

refer this post : http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/34563/where-is-database-connection-string-settingstxt-on-nopcommerce35.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Its actually there, I had the same issue just now after installing 3.5 and wanting to point it at an existing db, but not being able to find settings.txt and wondering if it had been moved to web.config or something more usual.

What you need to do is highlight presentation > nop.web > App_Data and then click show all files in the solution explorer. there you will see Setting.txt . Right click it and select include in project and you are good to go.